# a sortable and extensible naming scheme

Tags: data-structures

This is a question about a programming structure but I will use filenames to illustrate it:

I have a list of files:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
...
15.jpg
16.jpg
```

What naming scheme would be the most flexible to allow 
1) file sorting
2) adding files between existing

For example using 02.jpg instead of 2.jpg will place it before 16.jpg. This is what I need. But if I want to add 15a.jpg then it will be sorted before 15.jpg.

Are there some ready models for that problem?

Comment: Are you looking for a language agnostic solution?

Comment: I'm looking for a naming scheme. It will be use in some file format. So any language which can open and read binary file should do it.

Comment: That's harder for file names than if you have the freedom to choose your method of comparison. For example if you consider numbers that start with 0., it's easy to take two of them and find a number that's halfway in between, but they won't *lexicographically* sort correctly.

Comment: yes I know. That's why I'm asking here. I'm clueless. And need sorting lexicographically

Comment: I don't think it's possible, unless you can start with a large number of trailing zeroes and you can guarantee that you will never need more zeroes than provided.